# How to upgrade gettext / autopoint on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: gettext

I'm trying to compile a project that has a dependancy on `gettext` 0.19.3. I currently have 0.19.2 installed.

I've tried:

- `sudo apt-get install gettext`
- `sudo apt-get install autopoint`
- `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade gettext`
- `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade autopoint`

None of those commands will cause `gettext` to update. The terminal always says

```
gettext is already the newest version
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 138 not upgraded.
```

How do I install 0.19.3 or 0.19.4?

Answer (score 0):

Goto [launchpad](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/autopoint/download) and choose the mirror which is close to you. Then just download `autopoint` and install it through `dpkg`.

Example:

```
wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gettext/autopoint_0.19.7-2ubuntu3_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i autopoint_0.19.7-2ubuntu3_all.deb
sudo apt-get install -f # resolve any missing dependencies
```

Answer (score -1):

*first check your gettext version using 'gettext --version'
*then extract it and using command lines execute those comands.

*Prepare Gettext for compilation:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr    \
            --disable-static \
            --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gettext-0.19.7
```

*Compile the package:

```
make
```

*Install the package:

```
make install
chmod -v 0755 /usr/lib/preloadable_libintl.so
```

Comment: This answer concerns compiling gettext while the question was about installing via packages. Perhaps you should instruct readers to download the sources first and explain why you feel the package installation route is not an option